# What is a word for "each has a different preference/taste"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for "each has a different preference/taste"

I know there are phrases such as: *each to his/her own*, *different strokes for different folks*, etc. However, I remember there is a word for it.

Comment: Do you mean “diversity” or “individuality”?  Give an example of how you would use the word you’re looking for. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

[idiosyncrasy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idiosyncrasy) (ODOL)

> noun
>   **1** A mode of behaviour or way of thought peculiar to an individual.
>   ‘Each character bubbles with traits, ticks and idiosyncrasies.’